# Agregar multiples datos a un hijo númerico en Firebase en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

¿Hay alguna manera de agregar hijos numéricamente y vayan aumentando a medida que voy agregando un cliente? (001, 002, 003, .... 101, 102, 103) Estos serían el ID de cada cliente. He probado pero me los genera con un ID único.

[image: Árbol JSON de Firebase]

También quiero agregar apellidos, nombres y dni a cada cliente, pero al usar el método setValue() me los reemplaza y sólo me agrega 1 campo (apellidos) de los 3 que estoy ingresando.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference clientesRef = ref.child("clientes");

            String apellidos = txtApellidos.getText().toString();
            String nombres = txtNombres.getText().toString();
            clientesRef.child("apellidos").setValue(apellidos);
            clientesRef.child("nombres").setValue(nombres);
```

Comment: Segurísimo que se puede hacer fácilmente con `firebase-functions`. Voy a hacer unas pruebas y comento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que hayas encontrado una solución. Hace tiempo buscaba hacer lo mismo, pero no lo encontré por ninguna parte. Hasta que al final se me ocurrió una manera de hacerlo, tal vez no sea profesional, pero me funcionó.

paso 1.
crea el primer child(0) manualmente desde firebase.

paso 2. 
para que? Paraque... en android puedas recuperar el último child(). en ese caso, es el "0" que pusiste.

```
clientesRef.limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()... String ultimoCliente = dataSnapshot.getKey().toString
```

paso 3.
crea un String de la suma del valor obtenido "0" + 1

```
String nuevoCliente = ultimoCliente + 1;
```

paso 4.
ahora sabiendo que (0+1=1), el cliente que se registra ya tiene un id "1" el cual lo usas así:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference clientesRef = ref.child("clientes").child(nuevoCliente);

        Sring nuevoCliente = ultimoCliente + 1;

        String apellidos = txtApellidos.getText().toString();
        String nombres = txtNombres.getText().toString();

        clientesRef.child("apellidos").setValue(apellidos);
        clientesRef.child("nombres").setValue(nombres);
```

Y bien, espero que te funcione!! El próximo cliente cuando se registre, obtendrá el cliente "2"+1, por tanto su id será "3". y así sucesivamente...